# Disable snapper on Autodesk Forge Markup

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk-viewer

I have problem when try to implement some tools inside MarkUp.Code of Autodesk Forge. When i try to draw an arrow or text in my PDF drawing  it always go along with snapper. I've also try to disable it with snapper.clearSnapped() but nothing better.
Do anyone who know the solution for it ?
Thanks a lot !

```
 function DrawText(){
      var extension = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");

      extension.callSnapperMouseDown();
      extension.enterEditMode();

      extension.snapper.clearSnapped();
      extension.snapper.indicator.clearOverlays();

      var modeText = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeText(extension);
      extension.changeEditMode(modeText);

    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the extension's reference to the snapper:

```
ext.snapper=null
```

You can save a copy of the reference elsewhere so that you'd be able to restore if when needed.

Comment: Hi Bryan, it's work perfectly for me. Thank you very much !.

Comment: Do you know how to active snapper again ?

Comment: Like i mentioned `You can save a copy of the reference elsewhere so that you'd be able to restore (reassign to ext.snapper) when needed.`